# Scope of Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to learn and create a Facebook API on the go. However, I haven't found any page on the developer pages that specifies the scope of the Facebook API in great detail. I understand public information can be accessed using Graph API. But at the same time understand that further access is possible, not sure how much though.

Is there anyway to access the 'Edit news feed options' of a user that authorizes an application?

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand what you mean by "scope", but the Graph API is not more than a series of URLs to contact the facebook servers with queries and obtain answers in form of JSON objects.

You can start learning by looking at the reference for the API here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

There are unofficial APIs for every language you can imagine, for example java: http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/ , c#: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/ , etc.

To read the news feed, you can access it by:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=TOKEN (where TOKEN is the access token)

Fb will respond with a JSON object similar to the one pasted below.

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "11111_1111111111,
         "from": {
            "name": "Name",
            "id": "11111111"
         },
         "message": "SOME_MESSAGE",
         "actions": [
            {
               "name": "Comment",
               "link": "http://www.facebook.com/111111/posts/11111"
            },
            {
               "name": "Like",
               "link": "http://www.facebook.com/11111/posts/11111"
            }
         ],
         "type": "status",
         "created_time": "2011-04-20T20:19:04+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-04-20T20:19:04+0000"
      },
etc etc etc
],

   "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=TOKEN",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=TOKEN"
   }
}
```

Having that, you can use the ID for the person or the message to perform new queries, as explained in the FB API page:

> All of the objects in the Facebook
>   social graph are connected to each
>   other via relationships. Bret Taylor
>   is a fan of the Coca-Cola page, and
>   Bret Taylor and Arjun Banker are
>   friends. We call those relationships
>   connections in our API. You can
>   examine the connections between
>   objects using the URL structure
>   https://graph.facebook.com/ID/CONNECTION_TYPE.
>   The connections supported for people
>   and pages include:

Almost every information on FB is accessible through the Graph API, provided the user authorized the app with the rigth permissions:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/